# auto-formating tool for django html template files

Tags: linux, django, unix, vim, django-templates

Is there a *nix tool (or vim plug-in) that would allow me to automatically format django html template files?

Hitting the space bar hundreds of time does not sound like a good use of my time but then neither does leaving some weird formatting that is hard to read.

Comment: I use PyCharm and works like a ..charm.

Comment: @Wtower: Can I use it as script instead of an editor?  I do not want to learn a whole new editor just so I can format some file.  Seems a little excessive.

Comment: Well, it is an IDE so from your point of view an IDE comparing to an editor is for sure excessive. But why don't you use this to edit the whole django project.

Comment: @Wtower: Because I would rather not learn yet another editor/IDE per language I use. It's a pain when you code in many different languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Install [vim-jinja2-syntax plugin](https://github.com/Glench/Vim-Jinja2-Syntax) by putting `Glench/Vim-Jinja2-Syntax` when installing it with plugin manager ([vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug), [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) etc.)
2. Put `autocmd FileType html setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2` in the vim config file, which is usually at `~/.vimrc`.
3. run `gg=G` in django html file(aka jinja template)

Answer (score 1):

vim has a filter for fixing indentation (I think that's what you mean with "auto-formatting"): `=`. If you wan to indent the whole django html template file, just type `gg=G` and that will do the job. `gg` tells vim to go the the first line, `=` to indent and finally `G` to got to the end of the file.

You can read more about this on [vim docs](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_indentation).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this vim add-on for django related features

https://github.com/tweekmonster/django-plus.vim